# Как правильно написать javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пытаюсь написать функцию внутри которой идет пост запрос к php файлу, который возвращает строку, а потом вывести эту строку сообщением, но ничего не получается.

```
function topscores(){
 $.post(
 "topscores.php",
 onAjaxSuccess
 );

function onAjaxSuccess(data){
 return data;
}

return data;    
}

alert (topscores);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, так не будет работать, будет так:

```
function topscores(callback) {
    $.post(
        "topscores.php",
    onAjaxSuccess);

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
        callback(data);
    }
}

topscores(alert);
```